# Small monitor form for 1280x1024 resolution

Tags: display, resolution

Based on the size and resolution of my Macbook (screen 11.25in x 7, resolution 1280x800), you should be able to get 1280 x 1024 resolution on a monitor with a diagonal size of about 14.5 inches.  However, the normal size for a 1280x1024 monitor is 17in.  Does anyone know of a manufacturer making a smaller size monitor for this resolution?

Comment: See also "Monitors - inches vs resolution" at http://superuser.com/questions/60808/monitors-inches-vs-resolution

Answer (score 1):

There is no such panel made. 1280x1024 is only made in 19 and 17 inch. I do not know why you need this specific resolution/size, so tell us a bit more.
There are however notebook displays at 1400x1050 pixels that measure 14.1 or 15 inch. Maybe that is something for you. One model they were in is the Dell Inspiron 600.

Here you can order them as spare parts:

http://www.techexcess.net/dell-8j775-inspiron-600m-latitude-d600-14-1-laptop-lcd-screen-display-panel-sxga-1400x1050-matte-b-stock.aspx

Comment: Might be a bit hard to attach some DVI cable to that?

Comment: Who asked for a DVI cable?
But in fact, these replacement screens have a flat-cable version of DVI as interconnect. If your wish for a screen is so specific, i guess you won't botter about a bit of soldering.

Comment: I wasn't the question asker. :-) I didn't know such screens do in fact use some DVI interface. Good to know!

Comment: Why do I ask?  I've got a netbook and it would be nice to have a small, light monitor I could use as a second screen.  Most of my work for clients involves 1280x1024 and I use the netbook as a portable development machine - but I have to lug along a 17" monitor.

Comment: @unknown, if you're making 1280x1024 *websites* then please get a 1024x768 screen instead. ;-) (I much dislike websites that think that I like to browse full screen.)

Comment: @Arjan - not websites but desktop data entry screens.